# My custom built computer overheats for no apparent reason

Tags: cpu, desktop, cooling, temperature

I purchased computer parts and assembled the computer myself. The build is this one: [Part List](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/CJzDFd).

After installing the operating system (Windows 10) and drivers I noticed that my idle temperature was rather high, would fluctuate between 40~60°C and would settle around 55°C. The room temperature was about ~24°C

I thought I may have had a faulty liquid cooling unit. So I purchased a new one. After installing the second one, I was experiencing similar issues with similar temperatures. Although the room temp was closer to 21°C.

When I would load up video games (Overwatch or osu!) the temperature of the CPU would shoot up to 80°C+ and my computer would crash.

I checked all the configurations for CPU and the liquid cooling unit. Setting the fans to max rotation speeds and cooling unit to max cycles. This did not help.

I double checked all the cables and re-read the instructions to make sure everything was hooked up correctly.

After all that verification, and no results, I took my computer to UBreakIFix thinking the next step was to test all the different hardware components and thinking they could do it. They got back to me with in two weeks. They told me that they under clocked my CPU to 70% and they changed other settings on my computer. (It was rather vague and that's all I got out of it)

When I play Overwatch on max settings the CPU does stay below 60°C now, but to me it seems like a band-aid was applied to the issue rather than getting a proper answer to *why* the issue was occurring.

What I want to know is if the issue was actually fixed or if I'm just waiting for it to pop up again. This is all to vague for an online community, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: This CPU's normal operating temperature is 0C to 80C, it sounds to me like your cooler was just installed incorrectly or the thermal paste is missing/incorrectly applied.

Comment: the thermal paste came pre-applied although it was a thin layer, i mounted the liquid cooler pretty tightly and centered well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody can really say for you I don't think. Many factors can effect CPU temp. To think of some:

Voltage

Clock speed

Heatsink size

Heatsink paste/properly fixed down heatsink

Fans

CPU Load (% utilised)

I built a 6600k i5. That was amazingly cool (40 max load) but a friend has a 6700k that run's in 80's because cooler is too small and maybe other reasons.

High end i7 do come from factory being pushed a little harder eg 4.2ghz and sometimes they are higher voltage CPU.

Many people dont realise that for any CPU not all from the factory have the same voltage. They are all a little different and get set with different voltages. Some simply are running a tiny bit more voltage and become a hotter than everybody else with the same CPU.

Another problem is the AUTO voltage setting in the BIOS. You should take steps to verify what voltage you are at when AUTO is set. (hint: it isnt a fixed value but instead scales with the cpu mhz clock speed) so sometimes can end up higher than it needs to be.

Best to go to BIOS and set your voltage to AUTO and Manual clock to 4.2ghz, then load up little program Hardware monitor (HWmonitor.exe). Now read what is your voltage at idle, and your voltage at 100%. Now go set that voltage manual (say it was 1.3V was the reading then set 1.3V)

Now go check it again with HWmonitor the reading from manual setting voltage. Did setting it 1.3 in bios result in HW monitor reading 1.3 or 1.35. You need to get the same voltage on manual as you got on Auto so you might need to set it 1.28 to hit 1.3. Find what voltage AUTO really was.

Now that you know what is "your" Auto voltage you can try to slightly lower it until you cool down your CPU. Try to get voltage as low as u can where your pc will still boot. This is basically what overclocking is about except here you need to just get standard 4.2ghz running cool enough.

This is partly what you were told when "underclocked to 70%". With AUTO voltage then voltage scales lower as Clock scales lower so they have effectively lowered your voltage. You should take it back to 4.2ghz and see what is the lowest voltage it can boot at. Failing that maybe you should get a solid metal 120mm fan heatsink.

Edit: Also be careful with changing voltages. Around 0.2V over stock can begin to break and overheat it fast. When you are checking temps check with as many programs as possible rather than just HWmonitor as sometimes reading can be incorrect.